# Can you dynamically generate Test names for ScalaTest from input data?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a number of test data sets that run through the same ScalaTest  unit tests. I'd love if each test data set was it's own set of named tests so if one data set fails one of the tests i know exactly which one it was rather than going to a single test and looking on what file it failed. I just can't seem to find a way for the test name to be generated at runtime. I've looked at property and table based testing and currently am using `should behave like` to share fixtures, but none of these seem to do what I want.

Have I not uncovered the right testing approach in ScalaTest or is this not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a base test class, and extend it for each data set. Something like this:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

abstract class MyTestBase extends WordSpec with Matchers {

  def name: String
  def dataSet: List[Person]

  s"Data set $name" should {
    "have no zero-length names" in {
      dataSet.foreach { s => s.name should not be empty }
    }
  }
}

class TheTest extends MyTestBase {
  override lazy val name = "Family" // note lazy, otherwise initialization fails
  override val dataSet = List(Person("Mom", 53), Person("Dad", 50))
}
```

Which produces output like this:

```
TheTests:
Data set Family
- should have no zero-length names
```

Comment: Didn't even think about using string interpolation in the test name. Nice approach

Comment: Thanks :-) See my other answer below, if you want to continue using behavior functions.

Answer (score 7):

You can write dynamic test cases with ScalaTest like Jonathan Chow wrote in his blog here: http://blog.echo.sh/2013/05/12/dynamically-creating-tests-with-scalatest.html

However, I always prefer the `WordSpec` testing definitions and this also works with dynamic test cases just like Jonathan mentions.

```
class MyTest extends WordSpec with Matchers {
   "My test" should {
     Seq(1,2,3) foreach { count =>
       s"run test $count" in {
          count should be(count)
       }
     }
   }
}
```

When running this test it run 3 test cases

```
TestResults
  MyTest
    My test
      run test 1
      run test 2
      run test 3
```

ps. You can even do multiple test cases in the same `foreach` function using the same `count` variable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use scala string substitutions in your test names. Using [behavior functions](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_tests), something like this would work:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

trait PersonBehaviors { this: FlatSpec =>

  // or add data set name as a parameter to this function
  def personBehavior(person: => Person): Unit = {
    behavior of person.name

    it should s"have non-negative age: ${person.age}" in {
      assert(person.age >= 0)
    }
  }
}

class TheTest extends FlatSpec with PersonBehaviors {
  val person = Person("John", 32)

  personBehavior(person)
}
```

This produces output like this:

```
TheTest:
John
- should have non-negative age: 32
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using ScalaTest's clue mechanism so that any test failures can report as a clue which data set was being used?

> You can use the withClue construct provided by Assertions,
>   which is extended by every style trait in ScalaTest, to add
>   extra information to reports of failed or canceled tests.

See also the documentation on [AppendedClues](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.1/index.html#org.scalatest.AppendedClues)

Comment: That's what i'm doing now. I have one test and loop over the test sets and set the withClue for each iteration. I'd rather have n separate tests each with the name of the set in the test name

Comment: Why? What will you be able to do with different test names that you cannot do otherwise?

Comment: the test sets are different input scenarios. it would be nice to know if i fail on a scenario based on the test name rather than the test output. I.e. i have sets ``scenario1`` & ``scenario2``. With clue, there is one test for ``"test sets should pass condition X"`` and if it fails i have to look at the output to see if ``scenario1`` or ``scenario2`` failed. With separately generated test names, the test name would show me, e.g. ``"scenario2 should pass condition X"``